# Unclosed tag 'block'. Looking for one of: endblock

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

```
<!--this is my base.html file -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Jumbotron Template for Bootstrap</title>
</head>
<body>
{% block content %}  {% endblock %}
<p>&copy; Company 2014</p>
</body>
</html> 


<!-- this is my signup.html file-->
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}

    <form method = 'POST' action = ''>{% csrf_token %}

    <label for="your_name">Your name: </label>
    {{form.as_p}}
    <input type = 'submit'>
    </form>
{ % endblock % }
```

I am just getting error

> "Unclosed tag 'block'. Looking for one of: endblock"

Please help.

Answer (score 13):

It is important not to add extra spaces and follow the syntax. Replace:

```
{ % endblock % }
```

with:

```
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Also triple check and make sure you're not missing a `%` anywhere, because you don't want to be like me trying to debug this and not realized there was a missing `%` 

Answer (score 0):

Just change `{% block title %}` to `{% block content %}`.